# comparing hex string all return false

Tags: javascript, comparison

I am comparing the hex string below `value`:

```
'0xC6b250Dd4dD3372C6602200C78D900818627eC9e'
'0xC6b250Dd4dD3372C6602200C78D900818627eC9e'
'0x570324fd11272F2F980AfeBf09D680aC9F136B1k'
```

using:

```
if(value === '0x570324fd11272f2f980afebf09d680ac9f136b1k');
```

Why all return false? because the last one is same?

Comment: Because `===` is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript string comparison is case sensitive. You can either normalize value by converting to lower case characters before comparing with `value.toLowerCase()`.

Example:

```js
const values = ['0xC6b250Dd4dD3372C6602200C78D900818627eC9e', '0xC6b250Dd4dD3372C6602200C78D900818627eC9e', '0x570324fd11272F2F980AfeBf09D680aC9F136B1k'];

console.log(values.map(value => value.toLowerCase() === '0x570324fd11272f2f980afebf09d680ac9f136b1k'));
```